# Pipe PuTTY context to client clipboard?

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, putty, clipboard

Is there a command I can execute like

```
cat <long file> | clipboard
```

From within a PuTTY session (connected to Linux server) to my Windows client?

I know I can select an area in the PuTTY client which is instantly in the Windows clipboard,
but this is done by much scrolling with on a larger text.

I am totally aware that a command executed within the PuTTY session is getting executed in the servers context and is not connected with the Windows client, but maybe there is a command which PuTTY recognizes to copy the buffer?

Alternatively, what's the best / easiest / fastest way to copy large texts from a session into the client's clipboard?

Comment: I don't know if there's a command that can transfer to the clipboard, but I would just output to the screen, and use putty's log function to catch the output. See also: http://my.kualo.com/uk/knowledgebasekualo.php?kbcat=0&article=888

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to copy all the putty output to clipboard, there is a "Copy All To Clipboard" option available in context menu (right-click) from title bar of the putty window.

Comment: This is by far the fastest way to copy a large buffer.

Comment: this doesn't play nicely with tmux when `set -g mouse on`

Answer (score 4):

There is a putty patch doing exactly what you want.

http://ericmason.net/2010/04/putty-ssh-windows-clipboard-integration/

And this patch has been integrated into kitty.

Comment: kitty is a good point, it's open source. but this eric mason page i could not find the source of his "modified putty". Very dangerous.

Comment: @DanFromGermany The source code is provided as a small patch to original putty 0.60 source, and the patch link is at bottom of the blog, before comment area.This is direct  [ patch link](http://ericmason.net/putty/putty-0.60-clip.patch)

Comment: Using this with KiTTY, but I modified the function slightly to avoid using the `$*` as I feel weird about using that BASH expansion there. I went with `function wcb { cat <(echo -ne '\e''[5i') - <(echo -ne '\e''[4i') }` instead.

Answer (score 3):

2020 Answer. As mentioned in previous answers **it is possible**. Idk how about official Putty because i use [KiTTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/#!index.md) (enhanced version of Putty) instead.

But all you need is to set `Windows clipboard` in `Terminal > Remote-controlled printing` and then use following code as a bash script or a function or whatever you like and then pipe into it.

```
echo -ne '\e''[5i'
cat  -
echo -ne '\e''[4i'
```

Usage example: `cat <whatever> | puttyclipboard.sh`

PS: The content (and the original idea) of the dead website ericmason.net mentioned in previous answer can be found at [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20190228173528/http://ericmason.net/2010/04/putty-ssh-windows-clipboard-integration/)

Comment: This works fine from a regular bash session, but not if I run it inside tmux. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Thx, great answer. Works fine with Kitty, but not with Putty (there is no option `Windows clipboard` in the mentioned settings).

Answer (score 1):

I am using Linux Mint Cinnamon here and my version of PuTTY does't have contextual menu.

I had to copy selecting what I wanted to copy in PuTTY and clicking the middle button (scroll), and then paste it with that same button (instead of right click and paste).

Apparently Mint has two clipboards.

Comment: Please answers are not set for comment, if you can answer the question answer it properly

Comment: The initial comment wasn't meant to be criticism but to shed some light into why I was posting this answer. Anywho, I changed the answer .

Answer (score 0):

The link posted by @Sulisu is dead so here is the function it contained:

```
## WindowsClipboard Function, only use with KiTTY or modified Putty
function wclip {
  echo -ne '\e''[5i'
  cat $*
  echo -ne '\e''[4i'
  echo "Copied to Windows clipboard" 1>&2
}
```

Comment: Someone should edit the existing answers to include the function from the website and properly cite and quote the reference (even if it’s dead)

Answer (score -1):

run [Apache SSHD](https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/index.html)

then from your Linux box:

```
date | ssh -p 8000 myworkstation "cmd /c clip.exe"
```